# determine which table element is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, mouseclick-event

I made an HTML table and now i am trying to change the background color of the clicked element. The problem is the fact that the table elements don't have the exact same width.
When i press the corner of some elements it interprets it as the wrong one.
It doesn't always interpret it as the wrong one but i'd still like it to work every time

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var wsquare = 25, hsquare = 25;

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var m = parseInt(w / wsquare), n = parseInt(h / hsquare);
wsquare = w / m;
hsquare = h / n;

var col = [], pressed = [];
var starty = Math.floor(n / 2), startx = Math.floor(m / 3), endy = starty, endx = 2 * startx;

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  pressed[i] = [];
  col[i] = [];
  var row = table.insertRow(i);
  for(var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
    col[i][j] = '#FFFFFF';
    pressed[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

var col = '#585858';

table.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  x = Math.floor(e.clientX / wsquare);
  y = Math.floor(e.clientY / hsquare);

  if(!pressed[y][x]) {
    table.rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = col;
    pressed[y][x] = 1;
  }
  else {
    table.rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    pressed[y][x] = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
th, table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="" id = "all">
    <div class="table">
      <table id= "table">
      </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have added a `padding: 1px` to the table, th and td.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var wsquare = 25, hsquare = 25;

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var m = parseInt(w / wsquare), n = parseInt(h / hsquare);
wsquare = w / m;
hsquare = h / n;

var col = [], pressed = [];
var starty = Math.floor(n / 2), startx = Math.floor(m / 3), endy = starty, endx = 2 * startx;

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  pressed[i] = [];
  col[i] = [];
  var row = table.insertRow(i);
  for(var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
    col[i][j] = '#FFFFFF';
    pressed[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

var col = '#585858';

table.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  x = Math.floor(e.clientX / wsquare);
  y = Math.floor(e.clientY / hsquare);

  if(!pressed[y][x]) {
    table.rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = col;
    pressed[y][x] = 1;
  }
  else {
    table.rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    pressed[y][x] = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
th, table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 1px; // Observe this padding
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="" id = "all">
    <div class="table">
      <table id= "table">
      </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This i believe is a fix to some extend:

```
// border-collapse: collapse -> remove
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
```

Now the border is a little thicker than before but maybe you already know a good fix for that :)

Comment: for some reason choosing the table element still doesn't work properly for me